migrating to rails 7 testing manifest.js error
in migrating an application to rails 7.0
the following warning is issued;
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1.
Use `ActiveRecord.default_timezone` instead.
 (called from <top (required)> at /Volumes/dev/r/da_app/app/models/application_record.rb:1)

application_record.rb in no way refers to this
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_abstract_class
end

however, application.rb did.
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
was changed to
config.default_timezone = :local
It was a mistaken assumption that this change was sufficient...  what is incorrect here, then?

It could have been introduced by a gem (for example validates_timeliness)  can you post your Gemfile?

That is correct. Disabling the gem removes the error. upgrading to v 6.0 introduces other errors (probably will be valid only as of 7.1).  Rubygems page is misleading in this regard.
